# Android performance analysis and monitoring tool

Tags: android, performance, api, monitoring, analysis

I would like to create an app like http://www.littleeye.co but I don't know where to start. I searched across the google but I couldn't find any solution. Anyone please do help me with some Java APIs to connect and monitor android app in pc. I don't know whether it is permitted ask question like this in stackoverflow, but I since I didn't have any other options I'm asking. Thanks in advance friends.

Comment: I would recommended you to used [New Relic](https://rpm.newrelic.com/login?return_to=%2Faccounts%2F495728%2Fmobile%2Fsetup#tab-android_tabs=eclipse) for application monitoring in android or any mobile platform.This is the best monitoring tools ever and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry Guys, this tool is not available more.**

You can use "***Heliopause Dashboard***" tool to makes it easy to monitor and analyse your Android app's performance.

This is the best ever tool to check Android application's performance like **Memory Usage**, **Network Usage** and **CPU Usage** using this great tool.

You guys can download this great tool from **[here](http://www.heliopause.de/beta/?google-ads)** and also share with your friends to make great ever Android apps.

Comment: heliopause and little eye both were no longer available ,any other recent apps?